# Where can I find saved WiFi AP passwords?

Tags: wifi-password

I have a WiFi modem and somehow misplaced the password, but my phone is able to connect to it since the password is already save, but clicking on show password dosen't work.
How can I find the password from my phone?

Comment: As a thumb rule, always mention your device name and Android version before writing anything in the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you will need root acess.

Now download any root explorer app and navigate to:

```
data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Within the file you will find saved passwords.

Comment: Not that I needed to do this but I tested it and the passwords appear to be encrypted on my rooted Note 4. network={
 ssid="DontStealMyShit"
 psk=85f82e22102d1568ec1f9af4cfc04bff
 key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
 priority=3
 frequency=2462
 autojoin=1
 usable_internet=0
 skip_internet_check=0
}

network={
 ssid="ZomgWifi"
 psk=66108eabc875b1269b6f27c375db656892c0dbce103431761a7e23516267080a
 key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
 priority=4
 frequency=5240
 autojoin=1
 usable_internet=0
 skip_internet_check=0
}

**Edit:** One is for my 2.4ghz and the other is for my 5ghz.

Comment: Well this method worked for me and it doesn't have any encryption in it.(I am using Galaxy S-Duos GT-s7562) @jer3my

Comment: It's easily to view your password, use this awesome app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ihnel.com.wifipassrecovery
Now you can:
- View your connected wifi passwords
- Backup/restore easily
- Share passwords with your friends
- This is FREE APP.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/114324/96277), you need to have root access. Then  download an app called [Wifi password](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifipassword&hl=en) and grant it root access. It will show all the saved Wifi passwords in your phone.

To make sure that the app is not considered for other purpose(s), the app's author has mentioned:

> This app is not a Wi-Fi password cracker. It just shows memorized Wi-Fi passwords in settings.